# Laravel / Database - Security

Tags: database, laravel, security, roles

at the moment, I'm thinking about the security levels on database side  (in my case postgres) while using laravel.

So I came across upon this question:

F.e. I have two user roles in Laravel: User, Admin.

The user needs select, insert, update permission on the database.
The admin needs select, insert, update, delete and create at database level.

So in this case I would need 2 different connections in Laravel:

- one connection for the users
- one connection for the admin (with extended rights)

Is this common use? As I didn't find alot of information on this one in general.

How do u solve the problem of having specific database rights for different roles in Laravel?
Do u (only) rely on the internal Middleware?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Just out of my curiosity, why does Admin need to create new database tables at the application level? You don't mean database migrations when deploying a new feature release, do you?

Comment: The application creates formulars.. for every new formular a new table is needed (because of the customized attributes each formular has). This can be done using the "admin role" over the UI. Thought a long time about putting all formular structure and data into two tables (using json), but at the end tables for eacht formular are more structured and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to provide role based access control in a Laravel app is through the use of the *authorization* feature.

> In addition to providing built-in authentication services, Laravel also provides a simple way to authorize user actions against a given resource. For example, even though a user is authenticated, they may not be authorized to update or delete certain Eloquent models or database records managed by your application. Laravel's authorization features provide an easy, organized way of managing these types of authorization checks.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Comment: Thanks erikgaal, I already know the authorization feature. I thought it would be safer to set the authorizations on database and not application level.